# Docker compose for Mysql & Phpmyadmin : Connection timeout from the web interface

Tags: mysql, docker-compose, phpmyadmin

I'm fairly new to docker-compose and I try to create a dev environment for my web applications.
I have trouble making the database available to other containers.

To make the first step, I just try to make a simple mysql + phpmyadmin docker-compose file

Here it is :

```
version: "3"
services:
    db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        volumes:
            - /home/ubuntu/Projects/komalm/db:/var/lib/mysql
        restart: always
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: komalm
            MYSQL_DATABASE: komalm
            MYSQL_USER: komalm
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: komalm

    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin:latest
        depends_on:
            - db
        links:
            - db
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        environment:
            PMA_HOST: db
            PMA_PORT: 3306
            PMA_USER: komalm
            PMA_PASSWORD: komalm
            PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
```

The problem is that when I try to access the phpmyadin url (http://localhost:8080/) I got a timeout

I have tried a lot of things, can't list them here as I don't remember them all, but I tried to use link, to put the two services on the same network (other than the default), ...

I'm looking to make it work for two days now, and it drives me crazy, it can't be this complicated :D

Can someone please help me ?

Edit :
Here are some complentary informations :

I use `docker-compose up` to start the containers, `ctrl+c`when I want to quit, and then `docker-compose down` to stop the containers.

To be sure, I also rm -rf the directory where the database is located

Error message displayed by phpmyadmin :

```
 MySQL said: Cannot connect: invalid settings.

 mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out

 phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.
```

docker version

```
Client:
 Version:           20.10.7
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.13.8
 Git commit:        20.10.7-0ubuntu5.1
 Built:             Mon Nov  1 00:33:40 2021
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.12
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.16.13
  Git commit:       459d0df
  Built:            Wed Feb 23 14:28:23 2022
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.4.12
  GitCommit:        7b11cfaabd73bb80907dd23182b9347b4245eb5d
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.2
  GitCommit:        
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

docker-compose -v

```
docker-compose version 1.27.4, build unknown
```

cat /etc/*release

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=21.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=impish
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 21.10"
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 21.10"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="21.10"
VERSION="21.10 (Impish Indri)"
VERSION_CODENAME=impish
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
UBUNTU_CODENAME=impish
```

Log of the docker-compose up :

```
db_1          | 2022-03-25 10:13:29+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.37-1debian10 started.
db_1          | 2022-03-25 10:13:29+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
db_1          | 2022-03-25 10:13:29+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.37-1debian10 started.
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:30.302445Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:31.296260Z 0 [Warning] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1 is enabled. Please use TLSv1.2 or higher.
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:34.100862Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:34.101071Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:34.216828Z 0 [Warning] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1 is enabled. Please use TLSv1.2 or higher.
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:34.216831Z 0 [Warning] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1.1 is enabled. Please use TLSv1.2 or higher.
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:34.217642Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:34.217766Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:34.219687Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:34.229416Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:34.229819Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
db_1          | Version: '5.7.37'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
db_1          | 2022-03-25 10:13:34+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server started.
db_1          | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
db_1          | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
db_1          | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
db_1          | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
db_1          | 2022-03-25 10:13:36+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating database komalm
db_1          | 2022-03-25 10:13:36+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating user komalm
db_1          | 2022-03-25 10:13:36+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Giving user komalm access to schema komalm
db_1          | 
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:36.563351Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:36.564511Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:36.564673Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:36.564684Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:36.564694Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:36.564697Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:36.564816Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:36.564826Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:36.564833Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:36.564841Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:36.565033Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:36.565044Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:36.565052Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:36.565149Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:36.565153Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:36.565159Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:36.565253Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:36.565303Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:36.565329Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:36.565332Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:36.565334Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:36.667329Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:36.667856Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 220325 10:13:36
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.076156Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 12659898
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.078055Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.078076Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.078081Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.078085Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.078087Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.078255Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.078586Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
db_1          | 
db_1          | 2022-03-25 10:13:38+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server stopped
db_1          | 
db_1          | 2022-03-25 10:13:38+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.
db_1          | 
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.781280Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.783422Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.37) starting as process 1 ...
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.787035Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.787054Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.787057Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.787061Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.787065Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.787222Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.787563Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.787765Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.789846Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.799747Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.802778Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.814716Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.823232Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.823309Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.839525Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.840276Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.840293Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.840670Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.895218Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.37 started; log sequence number 12659898
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.895552Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.895819Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.900309Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 220325 10:13:38
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.906544Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.906597Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.906617Z 0 [Warning] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1 is enabled. Please use TLSv1.2 or higher.
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.906621Z 0 [Warning] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1.1 is enabled. Please use TLSv1.2 or higher.
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.907514Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.907574Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.908314Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.908364Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.908382Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.908409Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.910027Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.924376Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
db_1          | 2022-03-25T10:13:38.924604Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
db_1          | Version: '5.7.37'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
phpmyadmin_1  | 172.19.0.1 - - [25/Mar/2022:10:13:56 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4701 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0"
phpmyadmin_1  | 172.19.0.1 - - [25/Mar/2022:10:14:56 +0000] "GET /themes/dot.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 325 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0"
phpmyadmin_1  | 172.19.0.1 - - [25/Mar/2022:10:14:56 +0000] "GET /js/messages.php?l=en&v=5.1.3 HTTP/1.1" 200 8259 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0"
phpmyadmin_1  | 172.19.0.1 - - [25/Mar/2022:10:14:56 +0000] "GET /themes/pmahomme/css/printview.css?v=5.1.3 HTTP/1.1" 200 954 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0"
phpmyadmin_1  | 172.19.0.1 - - [25/Mar/2022:10:14:56 +0000] "GET /themes/pmahomme/img/b_help.png HTTP/1.1" 200 989 "http://localhost:8080/themes/pmahomme/css/theme.css?v=5.1.3&nocache=2076559093ltr&server=1" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0"
phpmyadmin_1  | 172.19.0.1 - - [25/Mar/2022:10:14:56 +0000] "GET /themes/pmahomme/img/s_error.png HTTP/1.1" 200 898 "http://localhost:8080/themes/pmahomme/css/theme.css?v=5.1.3&nocache=2076559093ltr&server=1" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0"
```

Comment: What is the exact command you're using to start this, please?

Comment: You shouldn't need the links directive at all; when you run `docker-compose up` it creates a new network and connects both containers to it automatically. If you were to use links, you'd use syntax like "db:foo" so you could also refer to the database server as host foo, but that isn't needed here at all.

Comment: Try running docker-compose ps to verify that both containers are running. Do you get any interesting output from the logs that are displayed? Your exact compose file works fine for me, so I suspect you could have something else going on that's causing problems.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @IsaacBennetch ! I added some complementary informatoions in the post.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that all looks correct to me. The eighth to last line says MySQL is listening and ready, we don't see any problems after that, the way you run Docker would show any errors immediately, and you've even taken care to remove the MySQL directory in case there were any odd artifacts left there from a previous failed startup.

Comment: I'd also try removing the network manually, the name is based on the folder your docker-compose.yml file is in but you can find it quickly with `docker network list` then remove it in my case with `docker network rm stackoverflow_default`. You could also try `docker-compose up --build` which will rebuild the whole stack; sometimes a configuration change won't trigger a rebuild and this is needed to clear the cached configurations, or even `docker-compose up --build --no-cache` (although the first one should be sufficient).

Comment: I gave up with this ubuntu, I tried on a rocky linux box, and it is working like a charm, I don't know what's appened on the other box :( Thanks @IsaacBennetch for your time !